Firebase Error: auth/invalid-app-credentials in Next.js project with Phone Auth
I'm currently working on a Next.js project and encountering an issue with Firebase's Phone Authentication. When using signInWithPhoneNumber() for phone authentication, I keep getting the error auth/invalid-app-credentials, despite having configured my Firebase API keys correctly.

r/Firebase - Firebase Error: auth/invalid-app-credentials in Next.js project with Phone Auth

When testing the endpoint https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendVerificationCode?key=, I receive the following response:
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }

Here's what I've already checked and tried:
It works for testing numbers but does not work for non-testing numbers. Previously, it also worked for non-testing numbers, but this issue started occurring suddenly two days ago without any changes to the code.
Interestingly, the phone authentication works correctly when the project is hosted (e.g., on Vercel), but encounters the auth/invalid-app-credentials error when running locally.

I am experiencing the same issue. It works when hosted, but does not on localhost. If you found a fix, it would be more than welcome.

I'm also experiencing the same issue.

I have created an issue in firebase-js-sdk repo:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/8387
Please add any details that you may find useful there so that we can get help

We're using Firebase Phone Auth in our Electron app, and it was working just fine about a week ago, and suddenly stopped working.. We're using electron-forge, I'm not sure how we can serve 127.0.0.1 on an electron app, especially with electron-forge. Appreciate any help!

In the authentication section of your Firebase project, go to settings and add the domain 127.0.0.1 in Authorized domains and place the URL 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in your browser(for example 127.0.0.1:3000 instead of localhost:3000).

hi! can i get an exaplnation to why does this happen and why does using 127.0.0.1 works?

hi! It can be used with 127.0.0.1 if a local server is used, while previously it could be used with the localhost domain. I don't know the reason for refusing to use the localhost hostname in the Firebase system. maybe because localhost is a hostname, and it must be resolved to an IP address by the system. Typically, it resolves to 127.0.0.1 (IPv4) or ::1 (IPv6), depending on the environment.
Inconsistent resolution (e.g., resolving to ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1) can cause issues if the firebase service or configuration expects IPv4 specifically.
